# How to include javascript in Elastix Module

Tags: linux, module, datepicker, elastix

I really need help including the datepicker from the monitoring module of elastix.

The problem is I can't find how to add to the head section of my module.
I want to use the existing js datepicker from the "monitoring" module.

(var/www/html/libs/js/jscalendar/calendar.js)

I am using elastix 2.3.0 ...

Please help and thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Include it in the smarty template, usually will be the filter.tpl for all the reports modules.